Azure IOT hub python package error in Raspberry Pi
I am using Raspberry Pi 4 and working on a project which involve azure-iot-hub. I have installed it using pip3 install azure-iot-hub and I am importing it like
from azure.iot.hub import IoTHubRegistryManager
from azure.iot.hub.models import CloudToDeviceMethod, CloudToDeviceMethodResult

But keeps getting below error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/developer/Documents/AWC-Device/app.py", line 14, in <module>
    from azure.iot.hub import IoTHubRegistryManager
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'azure.iot.hub'

I did pip3 list -v

So it is installed at /home/developer/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages. Other packages like azure-iot-device are also installed at the same location but do not give any error. I have tried moving the package from above location to /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages but still have the same error.
I have also tried following the accepted answer in this post but unable to understand it properly. Has anyone faced a similar issue and how to resolve it. Please help. Thanks

DO NOT post illegible pictures of text post TEXT
